# How to check symbolic link support in an easy and effortless manner?

Tags: python, operating-system

I need to check whether on this platform I have symbolic link support or not. I got this code from test package of Python.

```
_can_symlink = None
def can_symlink():
    global _can_symlink
    if _can_symlink is not None:
        return _can_symlink
    symlink_path = TESTFN + "can_symlink"
    try:
        os.symlink(TESTFN, symlink_path)
        can = True
    except (OSError, NotImplementedError, AttributeError):
        can = False
    else:
        os.remove(symlink_path)
    _can_symlink = can
    return can
```

Is this the best way? I am afraid that I got exception thrown not because I don't have symbolic link support, but not enough permission. So by performing additional checking on permission, is that sufficient to better this code? Or is there a better way to do this checking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK, this is the best way.  Note that some Microsoft filesystems support symlinks, and some don't.  Of course, the same is true of Linux and UNIX - if you have a FAT filesystem mounted in them, that won't support symlinks.

Two minor quibbles with your code above:

1. The can = True could be moved into the else; generally the smaller
   your try clause, the better
2. Using a global is one way of getting something with a global
   lifetime, but sadly, it's also (module) global in scope.  You can
   also give a defaulted parameter to a function to get global lifetime
   that is local in scope.  Or just use a class.

Answer (score 0):

I think, adding permission checking will solve the problem, but I think it is better to list the platform that support symbolic link and check the current platform.

```
>>> import platform
>>> platform.system()
'Windows'
```

It is simpler because platform will not add that much.